# Adding numbers together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Jquery code and i need to add the var data and a number together...

```
$('div[name=price]').html("");  
    $.post("getprice.php", { unit: $('input[name=property]:checked').val() , date: $('#car').val() + $('#smh').val()  } ,function(data){
        $('div[name=price]').html(data + 1);
        $('#bprice').val(data);
});
```

But data equals 499 but it just displays as 4991 when it should say 500

Thanks

Lee

Comment: I was close to make a joke about jQuery, addition and plugins...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options, since Javascript is defaulting to treating it as a string:

```
$('div[name=price]').html(parseInt(data, 10) + 1);

$('div[name=price]').html(data*1 + 1);
```

EDIT: I'm not sure I picked the right field you were talking about, but the idea is you have to convert a string to a numbers, and that is done by `parseInt` or multiplying by 1

Comment: `Number(data) + 1`, unless you want "499a" + 1 to equal 500.

Comment: @Marc: Using `Number` (`String`, `Boolean`, `Array`,...) is almost always bad. And getting `NaN` as result is not really better, is it?

Comment: Am I crazy or is there no `Integer` type in JavaScript? `parseInt` is a top-level function.

Comment: @Felix Kling, same result, less overhead, same intent.

Answer (score 2):

You need to coerce `data` to a number by writing `+data`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt`:

```
$('div[name=price]').html(parseInt(data, 10) + 1);
```

Comment: ok what if i want to do $('div[name=price]').html("Price: £" + parseInt(data, 10) + 1);

Comment: @Lee: Use parenthesis to group operations.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('div[name=price]').html(parseInt(data, 10) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : $('div[name=price]').html(data * 1 + 1);

Using the *1 tries to modify the type from string to number in JS.